# App build on iOS 7 looks really bad on iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6.1

I have made my application according to iOS 7. but i need to run it on iOS6 as well. But now, when i am testing it on iOS6, it is looking really bad..!!

how to customise it for iOS 6 now ? Please help. The searchbar has moved down, and the cells have shifted..

Comment: Please elaborate, is it the tableview you need help with, the design etc. Be more specific.

Comment: the search bar has moved down, and the cells have shifted..

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: Use autolayout to fix this

Comment: can you plesse elaborate @UndercoverDeveloper

Comment: Looks crappy on both.

Comment: Learn autolayout from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: ok.. thanks.. Will go through it

Answer (score 0):

You could try using https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit to make the iOS6 layout similar in style.

Alternatively you could fix the discrepancies in code, checking for iOS version and adjusting positions/background Color/images/everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you are worried about the backward compatibility, from advance to the older iOS, the best way is to learn about the difference. Try to understand what have come far from iOS 6 & whats new in iOS7. Please refer this optimizing guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html)

Also the more precise guide to what you are looking found is well defined here in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/TransitionGuide.pdf).

I am sure once you are setup with all "the stuff" that defines the differences (ios7 & ios6 transition), you will overcome the problems.